# Need assistance with a exec( string )

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am writing an exe string in sql 2012 and I am getting the following error.
Incorrect syntax near Group By.  Any assistance would be much appreciated in advance.

```
declare @counter int = (select count(1) from #temp)  SELECT * FROM #temp
declare @tab_name varchar(100)
declare @col_name varchar(100)

while (@counter > 0)
begin
set @tab_name = (select table_name from #temp where rn = @counter)
set @col_name = (select field_name from #temp where rn = @counter)

exec ('select 
'''+@tab_name+''','''+@col_name+''',max(len('+@col_name+')),'''+@col_name+''' 
from [x3v7].[LIVE].'+@tab_name+'''Group By'''+@col_name+'''Having 
max(len('+@col_name+'))>12''')
set @counter -= 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a the basic structure of a cursor loop with dynamic SQL to get you started.

The string concatenation is still a mess.  Clean it up using the [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) functions to generate the query.

```
declare @tab_name varchar(100)
declare @col_name varchar(100)

declare c cursor local for 
  select table_name, field_name 
  from #temp

open c;

fetch next from c into @tab_name, @col_name;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

  declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select 
'''+@tab_name+''','''+@col_name+''',max(len('+@col_name+')),'''+@col_name+''' 
from [x3v7].[LIVE].'+@tab_name+'''Group By'''+@col_name+'''Having 
max(len('+@col_name+'))>12'''

  print @sql
  --exec(@sql);

  fetch next from c into @tab_name, @col_name
end

close c;
deallocate c;
```